# Create multiple instance of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my iOS App, number of tab items would not be fixed. It will be decided run time. Suppose, there are 4 tabs I will have to show, then I will have to create 4 instance of the same `UIViewController` run time (Inside 4 different navigation controller).

Here is what we do to access a particular view controller:

```
id controller1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
[controller1 setTitle:@"Football"];
UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller1];
[arrControllers insertObject:nav1 atIndex:0];
```

What I want to do is to have 4 instance of navigation controller having instance of a same view controller. All 4 view controllers will have same function to perform (one will show videos of Football, one will show Basketball video..) Means, in story board, `MyViewController` is one view controller, but need to create different instances of that `MyViewController`

How I can do so? The only reason why I will have to do so is, tabs of tabbar will not fixed, those will be dynamic.

Please share anything helpful..

Comment: you need different instances of MyViewController, so call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier four times, I think, i might not have got your question clearly.

Comment: My view Controller is single in storyboard, which will be shown in Tabs as a different controllers. May be 5 as per the response of the server.

Comment: I doubt this is supported. `UIViewController` has a `navigationController` property intended to return ONE navigation controller.

Comment: It's really not bad to instantiate 4 view controllers and then configure them slightly differently. UIKit won't even load the view until they tap on the tab.

Comment: If  instantiate 4 view controllers, `viewDidLoad` is called only once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view controller may be contained by only one other view controller at a time.  Even if that weren't the case, I doubt you'd want the very same instance across tabs, since you'd be burdened with changing it's state each time the user changed tab.

The simpler setup is to create unique navigation vcs with unique roots in response to data from the server, e.g....

```
// you've figured out here that you need four tabs, based on
// a response from the server like...
NSArray *tabNames = @[ @"one", @"two", @"three" @"four"];  // from the server
NSArray *tabs = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (NSString *tabName in tabNames) {
    MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
    vc.title = tabName;
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [tabs addObject:nav];
}
// here, tabs is an array of view controllers that can
// be assigned to the tabBar viewControllers property
```